# Add login and user to SQL Server without using SMO

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, smo

in our company's product, we attach a database to SQL Server, and we need to add credentials to some accounts to the catalog.

Currently we're using SMO to do this, but this gives us problems (x86 vs x64, SQL Server 2005 vs 2008, etc)

Is there's anyway of adding a login (to the server) and a user (to the catalog) using SQL?

This is the current code to add login:

```
connection = new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection(this.connectionString));
Server server = new Server(connection);

//Drop existing login (if exist)
Login login = server.Logins[AccountName];
if (login != null)
    login.Drop();

//Create new login
login = new Login(server, AccountName);
login.LoginType = LoginType.WindowsUser;

login.Create();
DatabaseMapping mapping = new DatabaseMapping(login.Name, connection.DatabaseName, login.Name);
```

and to add user:

```
connection = new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection(this.connectionString));
Server server = new Server(connection);
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database database = server.Databases[CatalogName];
User user = server.Databases[CatalogName].Users[LoginName];
if (user != null)
    user.Drop();

user = new User(database, LoginName);
user.Login = LoginName;
user.Create();
user.AddToRole("db_owner");
```

I want to perform these operations using SQL. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, if you can do something in Smo but not SQL, you can always use Profiler to trace the SQL sent to the server while you run your Smo code. That's usually enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Never knew about this... +1 for the great advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CREATE LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751%28SQL.90%29.aspx) and [CREATE USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

To test for a [login first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176042%28SQL.90%29.aspx):

```
IF SUSER_ID('Login') IS NULL
```

To test for a [user first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187319%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

```
IF DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID('User') IS NULL
```

To add [user to role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750%28SQL.90%29.aspx):

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'Role', 'User'
```

FYI, SMO replicates SQL functionality. I don't think there is anything that can be done only SMO (there is plenty of SQL only stuff of course).